# Проблемма с суммированием чисел

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Есть код

```
/**
* @param $file_name integer
@param $string string examle: 564612ssa
*/ 
public static function replace($string,$file_name){
    $n = preg_replace_callback("/[^d]/i",array(new self,"ord"), $string);
    $indent = round((100/$file_name)*100*XML_Replace::INDENT);
    $n = intval($n);
    $n = $n + $indent;//проблема в этой строчке кода
    return $n;
}
protected function ord($matches){
    if(isset($matches[0])){
        return ord($matches[0]);
    }
}
```

На локалке все считает правельно, на сервере выводит одинаковый результат при параметрах

```
ClassName::replace('O12070681277',16)
ClassName::replace('O12070681275',16)
```

хотя должен разный! В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: присмотрелся к регулярному выражению `"/[^d]/i"` - телепатия подсказывает, что хотелось находить любые не цифровые символы.

Answer (score 3):

Вся загвоздка в функции [`intval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php). Если почитать документацию внимательно, то будет понятно, что если ей передать очень большое число (больше, чем `int`)? то она выдаст результат `2147483647` (на 32 битный системах).  Почему же у Вас на локалке все работает? да просто видимо на локалке 64 битная система, а в этом случае ограничение подымается до `9223372036854775807`.

Правда понять, что делает эта функция - не очень то и понятно. `$filename`, которое по факту просто целое - порадовало.

Comment: >$filename, которое по факту просто целое - порадовало

[что-то][1] наподобие

[1]:http://vk.com/photo-2541709_288283364

Comment: это тогда не `filename`, а хотя бы `file_index` или `file_id`.